# C# práctica de arrays

Tags: c#

Tengo un ejercicio para practicar Arrays que dice de pedir al usuario un día y un mes (ambos numéricos) y calcular los días restantes para fin de año. Lo he planteado de esta marea pero me aparece un error.

> Index was outside the bounds of the array.

Estoy dándole vueltas pero no encuentro el fallo. Gracias!

```
int[] meses = new int[12] { 31,28,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31 };
int TotalDiasAno = 0, DiasPasados = 0;

Console.WriteLine("Di un día y mes del año: ");
int dia = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
int mes = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());


for (int j = 0; j < meses.Length; j++) {
  TotalDiasAno += meses[j];
}

for (int i = 0; i < meses[mes - 1]; i++) {
  DiasPasados += meses[i] + dia;
}

Console.WriteLine("Quedan {0} días para fin de año.", (TotalDiasAno - DiasPasados));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Puedes cambiar un poco la lógica y solo contar desde el mes que te pasa el usuario. Entonces desde el día y mes que te pasa el usuario calculas los días que faltan para que termine ese mes y luego calculas los días restantes de los meses que siguen.

El código quedaría de la siguiente manera:

```
int[] meses = new int[12] {31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31};
int diasMesesRestante = 0;

Console.WriteLine("Di un día y mes del año: ");
int dia = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
int mes = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());


int diasMesActualRestantes = meses[mes-1] - dia;
        
for (int i = mes; i < meses.Length; i++) {
    diasMesesRestante += meses[i];
}
        
Console.WriteLine("Quedan {0} días para fin de año.", (diasMesActualRestantes + diasMesesRestante));
```

Comment: Entendido! Muchas gracias!